# Detect Button Press and get value web Browser to winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I just wondering on my Win Form Application C# I create web browser and navigate to web application

```
webBrowser.Navigate("http://192.168.1.100:8080/caseIndex/index.php");
```

Now inside web Application there will be column and button for user to press once user pass button the data within button (Contain parameter) will pass back to win form C# is it possible to do?

update: The when user pass it will redirect to anther URL and We need to get those parameter in URL to win form to process as well

Comment: it depends on what the button performs. If you have an actual link or a sample html share and describe more about requirement.

Comment: @RezaAghaei already update more detail

Comment: So it seems  it's enough to handle navigating event and parse the url.

Comment: @RezaAghaei But I not sure how to detect if user press button on web and get data to win form c#

Comment: Based on the url and available data of url.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yep understand but how to handle user button click?

Comment: Based on your description in answer an in the comments, I believe you don't need to handle `Click` event of an element. But if for any reason you want to handle it, you can find the element by Id or any other attribute and subscribe for click event, for example: `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button1").Click += button1_Click;`. But wince you said clicking on button cause navigation, so it's enough to handle `Navigating` event of `WebBrowser` and detect url parameters.